# Custom IUser implementation - Validate password

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

I have a problem using `UserManager.CheckPassword(...)` with a custom `IUser` implementation.

I am using .net Identity with Owin, creating my own implementations of `IUser` and `IUserStore`.

For the store, I only use the optional Email- and Password-Stores.

The `IUser` implementation is seen here, with the basic fields:

```
public class RegisteredUser : IUser<string>
{
    public RegisteredUser()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    public string Id { get; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
}
```

The problem occurs when validating the user when logging in.
I am unable to use the `SignInManager.PasswordSignIn(...)` as my store doesnt implement the LockoutStore.

Instead I use the `UserManager.CheckPassword(...)`, but this throws an FormatException, saying:

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string...

```
UserSignInManager manager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<UserSignInManager>();

RegisteredUser user = manager.UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email);
if (user != null && manager.UserManager.CheckPassword(user, model.Password))
{
    manager.SignIn(user, model.RememberMe, model.RememberMe);
    return RedirectToAction("UserProfile");
}
```

Thinking about this, I also fail to understand how the `CheckPassword()` method is able to check the password of my custom implementation without knowing where to look.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you post more data on UserManager. CheckPassword Method?

Comment: That is not my own implementation. I use microsofts default, but instantiate it with my own custom UserStore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright - Brainfart on my behalf..

The `UserManager` is able to check the password as my `UserStore` implements the following method

```
public Task<string> GetPasswordHashAsync(RegisteredUser user)
{
    string passwordHash = AWSUser.GetPasswordHash(user.Id);
    return Task.FromResult(passwordHash);

}
```

The problem was in the AWSUser class, which has the following method

```
public static string GetPasswordHash(string id)
{
    return tblUsers.Find(u => u.Id.Equals(id)).Id;
}
```

And as I am errorously returning the ID, that ofcourse fails..